# distributed architecture and data replication

Tags: architecture, orientdb, distributed

I'm looking to implement a very simple distributed architecture; 2 Masters node on 2 workstations ; A fedora workstation and another fedora VM hosted on a Windows computer.

I followed the installation procedure;

- copy the directory of the "databases" to the second station.
- start of first instance
- start of the second instance

The instances start correctly.

But a change on one side is not reflected on the other.

I don't see what I could have forgotten...

Answer (score 0):

this requires enabling, in the config/orientdb-server-config.xml file, the OHazelcastPlugin in each OrientDB.

The nodeName parameter is added with the node name and the enabled is set to true

```
<handler class="...OHazelcastPlugin">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="node01" name="nodeName"/>
    <parameter value="true"> name="enabled"/>
    ...
  </parameters>
</handler>
```

Also change, in the listener section, the port-range of the binary protocol to 2424-2430

In addition to configuring the config/hazelcast.xml file, disabling multicast and adding the tcp-ip section

```
<network>
  ...
  <join>
    <multicast enabled="false">
    ....
    </multicast>
    <tcp-ip enabled="true">
      <member>IPnode01:2434</member>
      <member>IPnode02:2434</member>
    </tcp-ip>
```

With the above, you run the first node and later the second, so that the latter is synchronized with what the first has.